# Outlook 2007 attachments wont preview

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, attachments, preview

When I get an email with an attachment in Outlook 2007 that I *should* be able to preview (ie - image, word doc, etc) I get the following error:

> This file cannot be previewed because of an error in the following previewer:
>
> Microsoft Outlook image previewer
>
> To open this file in its own program double-click it.

(obviously the previewer changes name depending on the type)

The computer is a clean install (it's only 5 days old) and I remember I was at one point able to preview within Outlook.

I'd really like this feature to be back working, I've tried the usual exit Outlook, restart Windows, etc but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when another program you install sets itself as the default 'Open with...' program for that particular file type (.jpg, .gif, etc)

Try changing the default "Open with..." program back to the Windows default (eg. for images set it back to Windows Picture Viewer) and see if you have better success after restarting Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed all the updates for the OS and Outlook? Might help.

http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-3051808.php

There was a similar issue with XP and Outlook Express which may have been fixed by an XP service pack.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing a repair install of Outlook and see if it helps